# Domain Aliases and SEO

Tags: seo, search-engines, multiple-domains

We have created a movie site & to optimize in search engines for other countries, we have created a alias of various domains, for example movie.co.uk, movie.de etc. How to get this optimized and avoid Google duplicate content?

Answer (score 2):

Just do a [301 redirect](http://www.webconfs.com/how-to-redirect-a-webpage.php) from all of the secondary domains to the main domain.